# Getting error while loading JSON into Bigquery using UI

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I have to load the JSON into Bigquery. As per the Bigquery documentation, I made my JSON in the correct formation i.e. Newline delimited with one JSON object each row.

Now, JSON file has around 10 million rows and while loading I get the below error:

Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 2165; errors: 1. Please look into the error stream for more details.

When I found the line 2165, it looks like as follows:

```
{"deviceId":"13231fd01222a28e","dow":"Wednesday","downloadFlag":"N","email":"clstone898@gmail.com","emailSha256":"1bdf11821f867799bde022ccb57a2e899f827c988b4275571ffd60279c863272","event":"streamStop","firebaseUID":"UDVC3hyQpBWLCnlhXhjAQBeI95Q2","halfHourFull":"08h1","liveFlag":"Y","localDate":"2018-02-07","localHalfHour":1,"login":"google","minutesSinceMidnight":497,"quarterHourFull":"08q2","stationName":"Fox hit 101.9","streamListenMethod":"BluetoothA2DPOutput","timestampLocal":"2018-02-07T08:017:04.679+11:00","timestampUTC":"2018-02-06T21:17:04.679Z"}
```

When I load this single line then it gets loaded successfully. Kindly guide/suggest what is incorrect here.

I'm loading this json from Bigquery UI using schema Auto-Detect option.

Sample records are as follows:

```
{"deviceId":"3c7a345dafcff93f","dow":"Tuesday","downloadFlag":"N","email":"psloper.ps@gmail.com","emailSha256":"1cebae8c35db32edcd35e746863fc65a04ac68f2f5b3350f2df477a86bfaa07d","event":"streamStop","firebaseUID":"AMFYYjsvZjauhCktJ5lUzZj0d3D2","halfHourFull":"21h2","liveFlag":"Y","localDate":"2018-02-06","localHalfHour":2,"login":"google","minutesSinceMidnight":1311,"quarterHourFull":"21q4","stationName":"hit 105","streamListenMethod":"Headphones","timestampLocal":"2018-02-06T21:51:40.216+10:00","timestampUTC":"2018-02-06T11:51:40.216Z"}
{"deviceId":"2f1a8c84c738b752","dow":"Wednesday","downloadFlag":"N","email":"kory.maxwell@icloud.com","emailSha256":"13348786c15bff95e4afb4968a9bdbe883b70206a737c02c89fc8215f2a4e101","event":"streamStop","facebookId":"1784054201892593","firebaseUID":"Tx1bHjP6dhaDB2nl2c7yi2KZHsq2","halfHourFull":"06h1","liveFlag":"Y","localDate":"2018-02-07","localHalfHour":1,"login":"facebook","minutesSinceMidnight":384,"quarterHourFull":"06q2","stationName":"hit 105","streamListenMethod":"BluetoothA2DPOutput","timestampLocal":"2018-02-07T06:24:44.533+10:00","timestampUTC":"2018-02-06T20:24:44.533Z"}
{"deviceId":"AA1D685F-6BF6-B0DC-0000-000000000000","dow":"Wednesday","email":"lozza073@bigpond.com","emailSha256":"525db286e9a35c9f9f55db0ce338762eee02c51955ede6b35afb7e808581664f","event":"streamStart","facebookId":"10215879897177171","firebaseUID":"f2efT61sW5gHTfgEbtNfyaUKWaF3","halfHourFull":"7h2","liveFlag":"Y","localDate":"2018-02-07","localHalfHour":2,"login":"facebook","minutesSinceMidnight":463,"quarterHourFull":"7q3","stationName":"Fox hit 101.9","streamListenMethod":"Speaker","timestampLocal":"2018-02-07T07:43:00.39+11:00","timestampUTC":"2018-02-06T20:43:00.39Z"}
{"deviceId":"AEFD39FC-B116-4063-0000-000000000000","dow":"Wednesday","event":"catchUpPause","facebookId":"379907925802180","firebaseUID":"vQPh9tbO3Yge88fpMyNUFzJO7dl1","halfHourFull":"7h2","liveFlag":"N","localDate":"2018-02-07","localHalfHour":2,"login":"facebook","minutesSinceMidnight":465,"quarterHourFull":"7q4","stationName":"Fox hit 101.9","streamListenMethod":"USBAudio","timestampLocal":"2018-02-07T07:45:08.524+11:00","timestampUTC":"2018-02-06T20:45:08.524Z"}
{"deviceId":"AA1D685F-6BF6-B0DC-0000-000000000000","dow":"Wednesday","email":"lozza073@bigpond.com","emailSha256":"525db286e9a35c9f9f55db0ce338762eee02c51955ede6b35afb7e808581664f","event":"streamStop","facebookId":"10215879897177171","firebaseUID":"f2efT61sW5gHTfgEbtNfyaUKWaF3","halfHourFull":"7h2","liveFlag":"Y","localDate":"2018-02-07","localHalfHour":2,"login":"facebook","minutesSinceMidnight":475,"quarterHourFull":"7q4","stationName":"Fox hit 101.9","streamListenMethod":"Speaker","timestampLocal":"2018-02-07T07:55:35.788+11:00","timestampUTC":"2018-02-06T20:55:35.788Z"}
{"deviceId":"AA1D685F-6BF6-B0DC-0000-000000000000","dow":"Wednesday","email":"lozza073@bigpond.com","emailSha256":"525db286e9a35c9f9f55db0ce338762eee02c51955ede6b35afb7e808581664f","event":"streamStart","facebookId":"10215879897177171","firebaseUID":"f2efT61sW5gHTfgEbtNfyaUKWaF3","halfHourFull":"7h2","liveFlag":"Y","localDate":"2018-02-07","localHalfHour":2,"login":"facebook","minutesSinceMidnight":477,"quarterHourFull":"7q4","stationName":"Fox hit 101.9","streamListenMethod":"Speaker","timestampLocal":"2018-02-07T07:57:42.343+11:00","timestampUTC":"2018-02-06T20:57:42.343Z"}
{"deviceId":"13231fd01222a28e","dow":"Wednesday","downloadFlag":"N","email":"clstone898@gmail.com","emailSha256":"1bdf11821f867799bde022ccb57a2e899f827c988b4275571ffd60279c863272","event":"streamStop","firebaseUID":"UDVC3hyQpBWLCnlhXhjAQBeI95Q2","halfHourFull":"08h1","liveFlag":"Y","localDate":"2018-02-07","localHalfHour":1,"login":"google","minutesSinceMidnight":497,"quarterHourFull":"08q2","stationName":"Fox hit 101.9","streamListenMethod":"BluetoothA2DPOutput","timestampLocal":"2018-02-07T08:017:04.679+11:00","timestampUTC":"2018-02-06T21:17:04.679Z"}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here's your first bit of help: Put your Json in a block quote, code block, or a spoiler and maybe run it through a formatter too

Comment: @Kwright02 Since this is an ndjson. I'm getting the below error when I'm putting it through a formatter Parse error on line 1:
...-01T00:01:47.136Z"}{"deviceId":"399a649
----------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got '{'

Answer (score 1):

Well, look to that specific 2165 line:

```
{"deviceId":"13231fd01222a28e","dow":"Wednesday","downloadFlag":"N","email":"clstone898@gmail.com","emailSha256":"1bdf11821f867799bde022ccb57a2e899f827c988b4275571ffd60279c863272","event":"streamStop","firebaseUID":"UDVC3hyQpBWLCnlhXhjAQBeI95Q2","halfHourFull":"08h1","liveFlag":"Y","localDate":"2018-02-07","localHalfHour":1,"login":"google","minutesSinceMidnight":497,"quarterHourFull":"08q2","stationName":"Fox hit 101.9","streamListenMethod":"BluetoothA2DPOutput","timestampLocal":"2018-02-07T08:017:04.679+11:00","timestampUTC":"2018-02-06T21:17:04.679Z"}
```

And specifically to:

> "timestampLocal":"2018-02-07T08:017:04.679+11:00"

And the error message:

> Couldn't convert value to timestamp: Could not parse
>   '2018-02-07T08:017:04.679+11:00' as a timestamp. Required format is
>   YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:SS[.SSSSSS]]

So, if you change "T08:017:04.679" to "T08:17:04.679" (17 minutes instead of 017) then it works. :)